# Does cluster id of hadoop node changes with time?

Tags: hadoop

Does cluster id of hadoop node changes with time? If yes, when does it change and what precautions I need to take while using the cluster id in JAVA code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cluster ID doesnot change in your landscape. It will change only when u reformat namenode. **So dont reformat namenode.**

Comment: Thanks. Can you share official doc from apache related to it? I need it to prove it to my supervisor :)

Comment: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/Federation.html

Comment: got it. Thanks :)
In what scenarios, I'll have to reformat name node?

Comment: When you have a brand new cluster you do it at beginning and  when you dont want any data  and mess up your system :) .

Comment: So, are you saying, after data is pumped in, I'll never have to reformat the system again? Hadoop will take care of crashes, data loss, etc.?

Comment: Yes you are correct. Hadoop will have multiple replication so it will take care.